# 3 Row Vertically Fluid Layout, Fluid height

Tags: html, css

I want to achieve a vertically fluid box model

```
|-------------|
|             |
|header 20%   |
|=============|
|             |
|             |
|content 60%  |
|             |
|-------------|
|             |
|footer 20%   |
|=============|
```

When i specify the body's height as 100% it doesnt work.

How do I get a vertically fluid solution in CSS.

Or do I need to use Javascript

JS:fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/EGesW/5/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
html {
    height:100%;
}
body{
    height:100%;
}
#header{
    background:#FF9933;
    min-height:20%;
}
#content{
    background:#DDD;
    min-height:60%;
}
#footer{
    background:#138808;
    min-height:20%;
}
```

Comment: thank you so much, where do I get such documentation/information?

Comment: There's problems with this one in mobile. I experienced, that you cannot scroll in iphone if content is greater than 100% but html and body have css heights of 100%.

Comment: Personnaly I started here (http://w3schools.com/css/default.asp) a few years ago. Also, I think that in IE 6 do not support html 100%.

Comment: @HerrSerker I tried this out in iphone and it worked http://jsfiddle.net/EGesW/22/

Comment: I meant it generally and not this example in particular, If you have your html and body 100% height and the content in the body is larger, than you can't scroll, because iPhone will scroll the whole window and not the content in the body, so iphone won't recognise, there is an overflow in the body

Answer (score 3):

the HTML tag is also classed as part of the DOM in CSS on most browsers. instead, apply your body style to the html too like so

```
html, body { height:100%; }
```

^^ as matthew said, beat me too it

Comment: thank you so much, where do I get such documentation/information?

Comment: Works, I was busy trying when the answers posted, check this fiddle I made : http://jsfiddle.net/EGesW/11/

Answer (score 2):

You have to set `html`'s height to 100% if you want the body to be at 100% (100% height only works if the parent element's height is set):

```
body,html{
    height:100%;
}
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/purmou/EGesW/8/)'s an example.