# Fluid, static, fluid - 3 row layout

Tags: html, css, layout

Okay, I've seen **[static](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8260994/3-row-vertically-fluid-layout-fluid-height), [fluid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16917340/htmlcss-layout-with-3-rows-middle-row-fluid-sandwiched-by-fixed-height-rows), static** layouts, but now I've come to a design that requires **fluid, static, fluid** layout.

As in:

```
+-------------------------------+
|             FLUID             |
+-------------------------------+
|      I SHALL                  |
|          TAKE 400             |
|              PIXELS           |
+-------------------------------+
|             FLUID             |
+-------------------------------+
```

How would I achieve this one with pure CSS?

Worth noting is that the fluid rows might be 0 pixels if the screen is too small.

As for what I have tried, nothing yet - have no clues what to begin with.

Comment: Why dont you make 100% for fluids and pixels for the static one to start off with?

Comment: "I shall take 400 pixels" Laughed so hard at this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `display: table-row;` on the elements.

[see fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jTZpa/)

Comment: "fluid rows might be 0 pixels"

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I managed to hack my way around with absolute positioning.

HTML:

```
<div id="header"></div>

<div id="content"></div>

<div id="footer"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#header, #footer
{
    background-color: blue;
    position: absolute;

    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;

    top: 0;
    left: 0;

    z-index: -1;
}

#footer
{
    top: auto;
    bottom: 0;
}

#content
{
    height: 400px;

    background-color: black;

    position: absolute;

    width: 100%;
    left: 0;

    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -200px;
}
```

While this one works, it seems usable only 3-row scenario... or, it will always fail to answer the No-SQL world famous question `does it scale?`. With that I mean, I doubt this will work for 4 rows, where three are being fluid, with one having a `min-height`.

[Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/psycketom/9KSgK/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this [simple layout structure](http://jsfiddle.net/VuDzq/)

**CSS**

```
.wrapper{
   width:100%;
}
.fluid{
    width:auto;
    background:red;
    padding:20px;
}
.fixed{
    width:360px;
    margin:0 auto;
    background:green;
    padding:20px;
}
```

Comment: "fluid rows might be 0 pixels"